# Creating single stream from substsreams

Tags: rxjs

I am new to reactive programming.
I have this observable:

[[7,2,5][4,3]]

I need to convert it to this:

[7,2,5,4,3]

How can I convert it with help of flatmap operator?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `mergeAll` or `concatAll`

```js
source.pipe(mergeAll());
source.pipe(concatAll());
```

Comment: thanks for the post. Can the same result be achieved with the mergeMap operator?

Comment: @Michael sure. `mergeAll()` is identical to  `mergeMap(i => i)`